# Why is it possible to write a boolean array to a parcel but not a boolean?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, ipc, parcelable

In the documentation for the Parcel it states a method exists

```
public final void writeBooleanArray (boolean[] val)
```

But there is no method for `writeBoolean(boolean val)`

There also exists:

```
public final void writeLong (long val)

public final void writeLongArray (long[] val)
```

So a similar pattern is available for other primitive types.

Can some one explain why this is?

Comment: Very good question. I am also very interested in this result.

Comment: I ask this every time reading a boolean becomes 3 lines instead of 1. =(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an open bug report on it:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5973

Evidently others agree with your assessment (and I do too).

Comment: You think the fact this has been an open issue for nearly 2 years is a reflection on a certain shortcoming google has in addressing android bugs as it seems so fundamental and simple, or do you think there may be some hidden architectural problem

Comment: At the very least they could add a facade that implements the writeInt(myBool ? 1 : 0) and back workaround...  That alone tells me there is no architectural obstacle.

Comment: In the spirit of open source, I strongly suggest you submit a patch :) http://source.android.com/source/index.html

Answer (score 1):

No reason at all, seems just a miss to me. :-) Write a boolean[1] if you need.

See [bug 5973](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5973).